# configurar ROOT_PATH

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando definir variables globales para conectarme a la base de datos de la siguiente manera, pero me suelta este error:

> ?
>   **Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'ROOT_PATH/application/config/database.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\libs')**

Archivo `app/application/config/globals.php`

```html
<?php
define ("ROOT_PATH", $_SERVER ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "/app");
```

Archivo `app/application/class/Core.php`

```html
 function dbConnect()
    {      
        require_once( ROOT_PATH . "/application/config/database.php");
        return $conn;
    }
```

Archivo `app/application/config/database.php`

```html
<?php
$conn =    null;
$host = 'Localhost';
$db =     '****';
$user = 'root';
$pwd =  "";
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db, $user, $pwd);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Seguro que ese `globals.php` se carga antes que `Core.php` intente cargar la conexión?

Comment: No sabría como mirar cual carga antes

Comment: El problema ES ese y no hay nada en el código de tu pregunta que le diga a PHP que debería hacer otra cosa. Ahora bien, es claro que usas smarty para los templates pero no vemos cómo lo configuraste. Tampoco sabemos si estás usando algún otro framework. Nos muestras, por favor?

Comment: Instalé smarty, pero aun no lo he usado ni configurado. Simplemente lo instalé

Comment: Tu pregunta sigue incompleta y, mientras esté así, sólo estaremos adivinando. Por favor, incluye toda la info relevante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede que tu quieres declarar una variable global y `define()` declara **constantes**. Si tu quieres seguir usando `define()`, entonces asegúrate que cargues el archivo que contiene esa variable al inicio de cada otro archivo donde lo vas a usar. Si por otra parte, quieres usar variables te recomiendo que leas sobre el tema ya que es un poco amplio. Te recomiendo [la página oficial de php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.globals.php) o [este post de GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php/). De cualquier otra forma, con una busqueda rápida en google lo encuentras.

**Recomendaciones**

De igual forma, quiero dejarte la forma que yo uso para establecer conexiones. Lo que yo hago es crear una clase llamada **Conexion** donde tengo todo lo que uso para hacer queries y establecer conexiones. Un ejemplo de esta clase sería:

```
    class Conexion
    {
        function __construct() {
            // Cualquier cosa que quieras hacer, como iniciar las sessiones por ejemplo
            if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE && session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
                session_start();
        }

        /**
         * 
         * It will create a PDO instance with the connection to the database
         *
         *
         * @return bool false will be returned if something went wrong when trying to connect with the database
         * @return PDO If everything it's ok, this will return an instance of PDO with the connection to the database
         */
        private function connect_to_db(string $host, string $database, string $user, string $password, array $options)
        {
            try {
                $instance = new PDO(
                    "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",
                    $user,
                    $password,
                    $options
                );
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                return false;
            }

            return $instance;
        }

        /**
         * It makes a query
         * 
         * @return false This function will return false if the query fail
         * @return array An array will be returned with the elements of the query
         * 
         */
        public function make_query(string $sql, array $arrayParams = null, bool $row_count = false) {
            // Connecting to database
            $this->conexion = $this->connect_to_db(
                Conexion::DB_SERVER,
                Conexion::DB_BBDD,
                Conexion::DB_USER,
                Conexion::DB_PASSWORD,
                Conexion::arrayOptions
            );

            // Creating an PDOStatement for preparing query
            $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
            // Executing the preparing query
            $stmt->execute($arrayParams);
            if ('00000' !== $stmt->errorCode())
                return false;

            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

            // Cleaning and closing conexion
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            $this->conexion = null;
            $stmt = null;

            return $row_count ? $affected_rows : $result;
        }

        // global variables
        private $conexion;
        private const DB_SERVER = "localhost";
        private const DB_BBDD = "nombre_base_de_datos";
        private const DB_USER = "root";
        private const DB_PASSWORD = "";
        private const arrayOptions = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'",
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );
    }
    $conexion = new Conexion();
```

Y a partir de esto, ya puedes hacer tus propias funciones para un CRUD. Recuerda que el `require_once` de esta clase debe ser la primera instrucción de cada archivo en el lo uses.

Espero te sirva y recuerda siempre documentar tu código :)